# Code-First Migration not working with Identity Accounts in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, migration, code-first, identity

I'm trying to set up code first migrations in an MVC 5 site that implements AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework version 1.0. I ran Enable-Migrations –EnableAutomaticMigrations from the package manager console and, as expected, it created the Configuration class. The application builds and runs but there are two errors that prevent the Seed() method from working. The problems are flagged with the red squiggly underline.

The first error is related to the class reference to the DbMigrationsConfiguration base class:  "**The type Models.ApplicationDbContext' must be convertible to 'System.Entity.DbContext' in order to  use it as a parameter 'TContext' in the generic class 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration**'"

The second error is related creating a UserManager object in the Seed method, i.e. var manager = new UserManager(new UserStore(new ApplicationDbContext())); This produces the error message "**Argument type Models.ApplicationDbContext' is not assignable to parameter type 'System.Entity.DbContext'**

Since none of this is my code I'm assuming there is a bug somewhere but I'm stuck on how to fix it.

Comment: ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I found that upgrading to EntityFramework 6.0.2 created the same errors for me. I was able to resolve the errors by reverting back to 6.0.0. (Package manager console command: "Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 6.0.0")